# JS to python lambda/list comp conversion

Tags: python, dictionary, reduce

Is it possible to convert this js code in python using the same map reduce?

```
var fs = require('fs')

var output = fs.readFileSync('data.txt', 'utf8')
    .trim()
    .split('\n')
    .map(line => line.split('\t'))
    .reduce((orders, line) => {
        orders[line[0]] = orders[line[0]] || []
        orders[line[0]].push({
            name: line[1],
            price: line[2],
            quantity: line[3]
        })
        return orders
    }, {})

console.log(output)
```

So far I have only until the map part of the code:

```
txt = open('data.txt').read()
mylist = map(lambda x: x.split('\t'), txt.strip().split('\n'))
```

Not sure if this is possible to do it in lambda/list comp. Any ways will do. Thanks guys!

---- UPDATE 1 ----
Thanks @Univerio for the answer

Additional learning. Do you guys have any idea whats the problem with this being thrown as NoneType for {}

```
with open("data.txt") as txt:
    output = reduce(lambda x,y : x.setdefault(y[0], []).append({"name": y[1], "price": y[2], "quantity": y[3]}).items(),\
        map(lambda x: x.split('\t'), txt.read().strip().split('\n')),\
        {})

print output
```

---- UPDATE 2 ----

Well it is ugly. But got it working with the same map reduce.

```
def update_orders(orders, line):                                                                                                                                       
    orders.setdefault(line[0], []).append({"name": line[1], "price": line[2], "quantity": line[3]})
    #orders[line[0]] = orders.get(line[0], []) + [{"name": line[1], "price": line[2], "quantity": line[3]}]
    return orders

with open("data.txt") as txt:
    output = reduce(lambda x,y : update_orders(x, y),\
        map(lambda x: x.split('\t'), txt.read().strip().split('\n')),\
        {})

print output
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what the code does and what input/output you expect. A good python solution won't mimic your original code line for line anyway.

Comment: @timgeb, it's a tab delimited file with 4 columns

Answer (score 1):

It's more idiomatic in Python (IMO, anyway) to use a loop instead of `reduce`. You can also take advantage of streaming file access this way:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    output = {}
    for line in f:
        key, name, price, quantity = line.strip().split("\t")
        output.setdefault(key, []).append({"name": name, "price": price, "quantity": quantity})
```

This doesn't do **exactly** what the JS version does with respect to whitespace handling, but it should be fine for sane inputs.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the output beautifully. Sorry, added my additional question above.

Comment: @codeffreak That's because the return value of `append()` is `None`, meaning you can't do `.items()` on it. The reducer function has to be span multiple lines (`setdefault` and `append`, then return `output`), so you can't use a lambda expression. This is why it's awkward (IMO) to do this as a `reduce` in Python, since you have to `def` the reducer as a separate function.